# Flipboard soundcloud player

Tags: ios, soundcloud

In Flipboard's most recent update, they added soundcloud integration. How did they integrate a custom player?

Is it possibly a webview, with custom player HTML: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the UI, but the audio playback is definitely implemented in obj c.
The SoundCloud custom player won't work since it is requiring adobe flash.

Comment: What do you suggest I reference in the docs to create something like this?

Comment: This is build with the AVPlayer.